# Can not use Websphere WebSphereUowTransactionManager with Spring 3.0 on WAS 7.0

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

We are trying to upgrade from Spring 1.2.8 to Spring 3.0
However when we are trying to configure txManager for Websphere I always get a class cast exception.
We tried based on the example provided by IBM which doesn't work.
I am using WAS 7.0 and Spring.3.0.5 and hibernate.3.6.jars...
Here is the Spring config:

```
        <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ewpDataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>com/fme/example/model/Person.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
     <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">ORIG</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
        <prop  key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">
                   org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
                </prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">
                 org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup
              </prop>
    </props>
    </property>
    </bean>

<!--  Our Data source --->
<bean id="ewpDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/TOI_ORIG" />
</bean>

<!--- Get the Web sphere Specific TX manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

I read this article and tried exactly as specified.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html
And also tried
http://robertmaldon.blogspot.com/2006/09/using-websphere-transaction-manager.html

But we are getting this Exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager] to required type [javax.transaction.TransactionManager] for property 'transactionManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:231)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:447)
```

I see that the class 
org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager
provided for Websphere doesn't implement javax.transaction.TransactionManager any where in the hierarchy.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working. In addition to the above hibernate settings here is what I did.

```
    The object of type WebSphereUowTransactionManager is not an instance of 
    javax.transaction.TransactionManager
    but there is superclass method inside WebSphereUowTransactionManager
    called getTransactionManager() 
    this returns object of type javax.transaction.TransactionManager


<bean id="wasUOWTxnManagerObj"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"/>

<!-- 
    Now call get getTransactionManager on WebSphereUowTransactionManager
            object.
 -->    
<bean id="tranSactionManager"
    class="javax.transaction.TransactionManager" 
    factory-bean="wasUOWTxnManagerObj"
    factory-method="getTransactionManager">
</bean>
```

With this change now you can use WebSphereUowTransactionManager. Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps also with other servers, whenever you need to get javax.transaction.TransactionManager from Spring TransactionManager.

Answer (score 2):

When using Spring you usually don't need to use `javax.transaction.TransactionManager` directly.

Use transaction management approaches provided by Spring instead, see [10. Transaction Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

Comment: Thanks but we want to use WebSphereUowTransactionManager, Please see my response below.I got it working.